# Excel or Programming - Find all sequences of cells that are in ascending order in a table

Tags: python, excel, sequence

I have imported a table into excel with over 100 rows to a column. I do not want to order the values of a column in ascending order. I would like to fetch a sublist or find all sequences of 3 cells in a column that have numbers INCREASING or DECREASING in order.

In the attached picture, the cells with thick outside borders are increasing. I want to fetch all sets of 3 cells which have numbers increasing for a column which may have over 100+ cells. Thank You!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pspu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')['A'].to_numpy()

ascending = pd.DataFrame([
    A[i:i + 3] for i in range(len(A) - 2) if A[i] < A[i + 1] < A[i + 2]
])
```